# Problem with passing STL containers using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

My goal is to be able to pass a std::map<double, double> from Python to C++, populate it in C++ and then see the results on the Python side. How is this achieved? I can't even get a std::vector to work.

I have a function definition in C++ like this

```
void predict(std::vector<T>& seq, std::map<T, double>& probabilities)
```

main.cpp looks like this

```
#include "node.h"
#include "probtree.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<double>);
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::map<double, double>);

namespace py = pybind11;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

}

PYBIND11_MODULE(sps_c, m){
    py::bind_vector<std::vector<double>>(m, "VectorD");
    py::bind_map<std::map<double, double>>(m, "MapDD");
    py::class_<ProbTree<double>>(m, "ProbTree")
        .def(py::init())
        .def("process", &ProbTree<double>::process)
        .def("predict", &ProbTree<double>::predict)
        ;
}
```

Nothing I expect to work works:

```
>>> import sps_c
>>> pt = sps_c.ProbTree
>>> vd = sps_c.VectorD
>>> m = sps_c.MapDD
>>> pt.process(vd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: process(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: sps_c.ProbTree, arg0: sps_c.VectorD) -> None

Invoked with: <class 'sps_c.VectorD'>
```

Maybe a List?

```
>>> pt.process([1.0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: process(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: sps_c.ProbTree, arg0: sps_c.VectorD) -> None

Invoked with: [1.0]
```

How do I make that work?

There is also an issue with STL methods not being available:

```
vd.push_back(1.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'sps_c.VectorD' has no attribute 'push_back'
```

Do I have to write a bunch of boilerplate to get STL containers to work?

Answer (score 2):

Your first example doesn't work because you're calling a method with a class and not with an instance. This should work, I think:

```
>>> pt = sps_c.ProbTree()
>>> vd = sps_c.VectorD()
>>> pt.process(vd)
```

Regarding your second example: There's no automatic type conversion, so you'll need to convert yourself:

```
>>> pt_instance.process(sps_c.VectorD(vd))
```

About the third example: `push_back` and other methods are available under their common Python names. This is not well documented, so here's a list of them ([from here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/b3573ac9615b705d6e5b9bf598a3378edf079f06/include/pybind11/stl_bind.h)):

`bind_vector` exposes `append`, `clear`, `extend`, `insert`, `pop`, and some iterator methods.
`bind_map` exposes `keys`, `values`, `items`, and some iterator methods.

Those methods might not be available if the contained types are not copyable.

Comment: Yea, dumb mistake forgetting the parenthesis. Thanks for pointing out the available methods. I was able to get it to work after removing #include <pybind11/stl.h>, PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<double>);, and PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::map<double, double>); which were missing from here: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_stl_binders.cpp